# Alternatives to PHP Cron Job for Long Running Jobs

Tags: php, python, cron, web-hosting

We have a website that lists links to blogs in realtime. The problem is that the pages are slow to load because they are reading data from the various source sites.

I wrote a PHP script that creates an HTML version of each page. This runs once each hour. The problem is that the PHP script is timing out before it finishes all the pages. I know that I could increase the execute time allowed for PHP scripts, but this does not seem like the most efficient way to handle the issue.

Is there another way to do this? I just don't know what to begin looking for - PERL? JAVA? Python? How do these scripts run on a server? What should I look for from my web host?

Comment: If that's all your doing PHP is fine.  Our servers do not have a max execution time when running php from command line.  We use PHP for a lot of crons, actually.

Comment: Is this CLI (command line) PHP? There should be [no timeout set for CLI tasks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

Comment: No... I am doing this for a friend, they are running on GoDaddy...

Comment: Their host is immaterial. How is this script being invoked?

Comment: It is a PHP file being called by a Cron Job. There is an array of 20 pages that it cycles through. If you run the script through the browser it finishes the first ~15 pages and then gives a timeout error. When we run it via the Cron Job, the same result occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different solution might be to use a database, and not bite off so much work at once.  Make a table listing the sites you pull, and store when they were last pulled.  Then have the cron pull out 1 or 2 that haven't been pulled in a while.  Have it run often, then you'll always have fresh data, but the script will have an easier time working as its not trying to do so much at once.  This concept will scale well.

Answer (score 2):

Python with [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) will probably do a good job. Also, do I understand this right: you have a site that aggregates data from other sites, and it's all generated static HTML? It sounds like you're kind of using HTML as a database, so maybe consider using a proper one.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that your original problem is one of network latency ("pages are slow to load") I see no reason to believe that PHP is the bottleneck here. I doubt changing languages will affect your script run time.